# What's the difference between Comparable<?> and <? extends Comparable<?>>

Tags: java, generics

What's the difference between the following 2 lists:

```
List<? extends Comparable<?>> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<Comparable<?>> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
```

What should be the type of the elements that I can insert to `list1`?

Comment: If you really intend to insert elements into `list1`, then don't use a wildcard type argument. You should already know the type of element you'd be inserting.

Comment: @ernest_k you're right... But is there any difference between the two lists? When should I use <? extends Comparable<?>> ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you defined it is not very useful, but both of those have their usages.

Let's start with the second one and look at `List.containsAll()` implementation:

```
public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
        for (Object e : c)
            if (!contains(e))
                return false;
        return true;
}
```

Notice that you'll usually want to use unbounded wildcard when you want to threat everything as an Object. Like in this case. You can read more about it here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/unboundedWildcards.html

Now let's look at your first example, with the upper bounded wildcard.

First, to your question of how to populate it. You can do that using the copy constructor:

```
class K implements Comparable<K> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo( K o) {
        return 0;
    }
}

class K2 implements Comparable<K2> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(K2 o) { return 0; }
}


// Works
List<? extends Comparable<?>> list1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new K(), new K2()));
```

Useful property is that user of this list won't be able to add elements to it without using reflection (except nulls, but I wouldn't call it very useful).

You can read more about that here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html

Comment: Not a full true, you can insert `null`, since `null` is a member of any type.

Comment: @SergeyProkofiev I corrected my answer a bit, although I wouldn't call it very useful.